# I want to parse a Gson information but getting errors

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit

I am trying to send the data of source and destination.

```
public void sendPost(final SearchSendModel searchSendModel){
    //public void sendPost( String source, String destination){
        Call call = mAPIService.sendSearch(searchSendModel);
        //Call call = mAPIService.sendSearch(source, destination);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SearchModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SearchModel> call, Response<SearchModel> response) {
                Toast.makeText(Search.this, " Responce " +response.body(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.v("Responce", "Responce "+response.body());
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    SearchModel searchResponse = response.body();
                    assert searchResponse != null;

                    String content = "";
                    content += "Code: " +response.code() +"\n";
                    content += "vech_id: " + searchResponse.getVechId() +"\n";
                    content += "model_no: " + searchResponse.getModelNo() +"\n";
                    content += "reg_no: " +searchResponse.getRegNo() +"\n";
                    content += "delivery_start_date: " +searchResponse.getDeliveryStartDate() +"\n";
                    content += "delivery_end_date: " +searchResponse.getDeliveryEndDate() +"\n";
                    content += "full_percent: " +searchResponse.getFullPercent() +"\n";
                    content += "approval_status: " +searchResponse.getApprovalStatus() +"\n";
                    content +="source: " +searchResponse.getSource() +"\n";
                    content += "destination: " +searchResponse.getDestination() +"\n\n";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),content,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    searchModelList.add(searchResponse);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something is error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

This is the Json response which i am expecting:

```
[
    {
        "vech_id": "30",
        "model_no": "8956",
        "reg_no": "98765",
        "delivery_start_date": "2020-03-18",
        "delivery_end_date": "2020-06-24",
        "full_percent": "0.14",
        "approval_status": "1",
        "source": "ranchi",
        "destination": "garwah"
    }
]
```

Interface for API is:

```
@POST("search_vehicle.php")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<SearchSendModel> sendSearch(@Body SearchSendModel searchSendModel);
```

SearchSendModel.java

```
public class SearchSendModel {

    public SearchSendModel(String source, String destination) {
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    @SerializedName("source")
    private String source;

    @SerializedName("destination")
    private String destination;

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error always:
java.lang.IllegalStateException:Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 2 column 2 path$

Comment: where are you serializing it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your onResponse should use `List<SearchModel>` instead of `SearchModel`. Your response format is array.

Comment: Yes,I have changed the onResponse but again in the code 'searchModelList.add(searchResponse);' this line is giving error, where searchModelList is a List<> of ArrayList()<> type

Comment: Your `response.body` is now a List, therefore it may cause error when `searchModelList.add(searchResponse);`

Comment: How can I remove this error. Can you help me what should i use here

Comment: you can use `addAll` instead